# Testing Two Classes With Each Other in Pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, integration-testing, pytest, tdd

I just started learning about writing unit tests with `pytest` but I cannot find anything about testing to check if 2 classes work properly together where one class takes the output of the second class, such as

```
assert bar.bar(foo.foo('hello')) == 'hellofoobar'
```

Should pytest be used for running such tests that involve 2 classes? If so, should this test be written in `test_foo.py` or `test_bar.py`?

Will such a test be known as integration tests?

**Foo.py**

```
class Foo:
    def foo(self, x):
        return f'{x}foo'
```

**Bar.py**

```
class Bar:
    def bar(self, x):
        return f'{x}bar'
```

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest

from .Foo import Foo
from .Bar import Bar

@pytest.fixture
def foo():
    return Foo()

@pytest.fixture
def bar():
    return Bar()
```

**test_foo.py**

```
def test_foo(foo):
    assert foo.foo('hello') == 'hellofoo'
```

**test_bar.py**

```
def test_bar(bar):
    assert bar.bar('world') == 'worldbar'
```

**__init__.py**

Comment: What does this test?  Does it test foo or bar?

Comment: @MarcelWilson The test should test the output of `bar.bar()` after passing it the output of `foo.foo()`.

Comment: @MarcelWilson `assert bar.bar(foo.foo('hello')) == 'hellofoobar'`

Comment: I would say it belongs to `test_bar` then, no?

Comment: Think of it this way: it doesn't matter where the input came from.  The input could have been an int or another object.  What matters is how `bar.bar()` handles the input.  In `test_foo` you would then have a different test confirming the output of `foo.foo()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is perfectly fine.  It expects that both `Foo` and `Bar` are working properly.  In that case, I think you could call it an integration test.

**test_bar.py**

```py
def test_bar_with_foo(bar, foo):
    assert bar.bar(foo.foo('hello')) == 'hellofoobar'
```

The need for this type of test might depend on how complex each class is.  In the stated case (which is super simple) I think it would be ok to get away with breaking up the tests; meaning if `test_bar.test_bar` passes and `test_foo.test_foo` passes then `test_bar.test_bar_with_foo` becomes redundant.

If we break down the test and assume `Foo` returns the correct thing the test starts to look something like the below. At which point the question arises; does this test provide further value beyond `test_bar.test_bar`?

**test_bar.py**

```py
def test_bar_2(bar):
    assert bar.bar('hellofoo') == 'hellofoobar'
```